# Remove similar text from website update code

Tags: php

Output-

```
Dubbed: Basilisk The Ouka Ninja Scrolls Episode 06 added 2 hours ago

Dubbed: YuGiOh ArcV Episode 131 added 2 hours ago

Dubbed: Dragon Ball Super Episode 53 added 2 hours ago

Dubbed: Voltron Legendary Defender Season 5 Episode 06 added 2 hours ago

Dubbed: Voltron Legendary Defender Season 5 Episode 05 added 2 hours ago

**Voltron Legendary Defender Season 5 Show 2 Episode on update. i Just want to show latest one.**
```

Code

```
$up_data = $db->select("SELECT * 
                        FROM `". MAI_PREFIX ."files` 
                        WHERE size > 0 
                        ORDER BY `id` DESC 
                        LIMIT 0,20");

$plugins->run_hook("index_updates");
if($up_data){
    foreach($up_data as $udata){

        $value = explode(" | ", $udata->name);
        $a = array_shift($value);
        list($b, $c) = explode(" Episode ", $a);
        list($d, $url) = explode(" ", $c);
        $string = 'Dubbed';
        $string2 = 'Subbed';
        //if (strstr($string, $url)) { // mine version
        if (strpos($string, $url) !== FALSE) { 
            $e = '<span style="color: green">'.$url.'</span>'; 
        }
        elseif (strpos($string2, $url) !== FALSE) { 
            $e = '<span style="color: blue">'.$url.'</span>'; 
        }else {
            $e = '<span style="color: #D74894;">'.$url.'</span>';
        }

        $t=tsince($udata->time,$lang->time_v);
        $updates .= sprintf("<div class='update_l'><b>".$e.":</b> <a href='$set->url/episode/$udata->id/".mai_converturl($a).".html'>$b <b style='color: gray'>Episode $d</b></a> added $t ago</div>");
    }
    $updates .="</div><div class='more'><a href='$set->url/more_updates.php'>[More Updates..]</a></div>";
}else
    $updates .= $lang->no_data;
}
```

Comment: What about simply not printing the unwanted output? And does the code relate in any way to your question?

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: What is the question here?